# Get/Subscribe to stasis message (asterisk ARI)

Tags: java, asterisk

I am trying to send messages from a custum asterisk plugin to my application.

After some effort, I can send stasis message from my plugin, but I don't know how to handle them in java. (I use ari4java project).

On the plugin I send my message with two different methods :

```
stasis_publish("StasisTest", msg);
// or
int result = stasis_app_send("StasisTest", inte);
```

I can get the message in the plugin, so I suppose there are sent to the application.

First my extension.conf

```
exten => 3000,1,NoOp(test ARI)
 same => n,Answer()
 same => n,StasisTest()
```

On the java side, I don't know where the message can be received, I have supposed there are handled by AriCallback or AriCallback :

```
    private static class DummyCallBack implements AriCallback<Message> {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Message result) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Dummy message callback receive [%s] with class [%s]",
                    result.getType(),
                    result.getClass()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(RestException e) {
            System.out.println("fail callback message");
        }
    }

    private static class AppDummyCallback implements AriCallback<ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.Application> {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.Application result) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Dummy Application callback receive name [%s] with class [%s]",
                    result.getName(),
                    result.getClass()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(RestException e) {
            System.out.println("fail callback application");
        }
    }
```

I register to the ARI (that's working fine):

```
ari = AriFactory.nettyHttp(url, username, password, AriVersion.ARI_1_7_0);
```

And I try to get the message notification :

```
public static AriApplication createAriApplication(final ARI ari,
                                                      final String applicationName,
                                                      final EndpointTypes endpointTypes,
                                                      final AriCallback<Message> callback,
                                                      final AriCallback<Application> appHandler
                                                      ) throws ARIException {
    ActionEvents actionApplications = ari.getActionImpl(ActionEvents.class);
        actionApplications.eventWebsocket(applicationName, callback);

        ari.applications().subscribe(applicationName, endpointTypes.getEndpoint(), appHandler);
        return new AriApplication(ari, applicationName, callback);
    }

 public AriApplication(final ARI ari,
                          final String applicationName,
                          final AriCallback<Message> callback) throws ARIException {
        this.ari = ari;

        this.applicationName = applicationName;
        ActionEvents actionEvents = ari.getActionImpl(ActionEvents.class);
        actionEvents.eventWebsocket(applicationName, callback);
    }
```

When I am making a call on [3000], I get the following output :

```
Dummy Application callback receive name [StasisTest] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.Application_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ApplicationReplaced_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.EndpointStateChange_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelCreated_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelStateChange_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelDialplan_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelDialplan_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelStateChange_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelDialplan_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelHangupRequest_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelVarset_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.ChannelDestroyed_impl_ari_1_7_0]
Dummy message callback receive [null] with class [class ch.loway.oss.ari4java.generated.ari_1_7_0.models.EndpointStateChange_impl_ari_1_7_0]
```

I suppose no one of this message are mine message, how can I get back this stasis message ? Are they send to the ARI ? If not, what kind of message can I send between ARI and my plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

I used your example s a jumping off point for my own project, here's what I've come up with so far:

```
private static class DummyCallBack implements AriCallback<Message> {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Message result) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Dummy message callback receive [%s] with class [%s]",
                result.getType(),
                result.getClass()));

        if (result instanceof StasisStart)
        {
            StasisStart stasisStart = (StasisStart)result;
            System.out.println
            (
                String.format("StasisStart - Channel: %s State: %s", stasisStart.getChannel().getId(), stasisStart.getChannel().getState())
            );

        } else if (result instanceof ChannelDtmfReceived) {

            ChannelDtmfReceived channelDtmfReceived = (ChannelDtmfReceived)result;
            System.out.println
            (
                String.format("ChannelDtmfReceived received - Channel: %s Digit: %s", channelDtmfReceived.getChannel().getId(), channelDtmfReceived.getDigit())
            );

        } else if (result instanceof ChannelHangupRequest) {

            ChannelHangupRequest channelHangupRequest = (ChannelHangupRequest)result;

            System.out.println
            (
                String.format("ChannelHangupRequest - Channel: %s", channelHangupRequest.getChannel().getId())
            );

        } else if (result instanceof StasisEnd) {

            StasisEnd stasisEnd = (StasisEnd)result;

            System.out.println
            (
                String.format("Stasis End")
            );
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(RestException e) {
        System.out.println("fail callback message");
    }
}
```